# Ruby PG gem connection issue

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra

I've searched several related posts for the issue I'm having but wasn't able to find an answer. I'm a student in a coding program where most people use Mac, but I'm on Windows ( 7, Pro, 64 ) - because of that I'm a bit locked in to the tools/software I'll post here.

I'm trying to open a connection through Ruby with the pg gem, and I'm using Sinatra and PostgreSQL. I've established the server, database, and configuration path variables for PostgreSQL, and I've successfully installed pg gem (didn't have an issue there as in some of the other posts) with the line:

`gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin`

So the problem is that when I boot up Sinatra and go to the localhost,
I get a NoMethodError, Undefined Method for nil:NilClass on a method that otherwise works for Mac users.

The method is:

```
configure :development do
  set :db_config, { dbname: "news_aggregator_development" }
end

configure :test do
  set :db_config, { dbname: "news_aggregator_test" }
end

def db_connection
  begin
    connection = PG.connect(Sinatra::Application.db_config)
    yield(connection)
  ensure
    connection.close
  end
end

get '/articles' do
  @results = db_connection do |conn|
    conn.exec("SELECT * FROM articles")
  end
  erb :index
end
```

`connection` returns `nil`, and so the `close` method returns with an undefined method error. I don't think there is a syntax error as I've checked with others regarding this, and I'm thinking it might be related to a connection error with pg.

First time post so please go easy on me =) Apologies if I've left out any needed information - let me know what more context could be helpful and I will try to provide it! Thank you!

Comment: Is the db server running?

Comment: Yes, I checked that

Comment: If you make your `db_connection` method a helper, you can use `settings.db_config` instead of `Sinatra::Application.db_config`. Where are you setting the DB host, user, password, etc.?

Comment: @mwp: I'm not sure I follow; I thought my db_connection method is already a helper method? How would I use settings.db_config?

Comment: I've just been setting DB host, user, password through psql or pgadminIII; the error doesn't change though if I explicitly connect to a database - e.g. `PG.Connect(dbname: "...")`

Comment: Re: helpers, methods have to be wrapped in a `helpers {}` block in order to have access to Sinatra instance and class methods and variables. Re: connect, I still don't understand where you are setting the host, user, password, etc. You want something like `PG.connect(host: 'localhost', port: 5432, user: 'foo', password: 'bar', dbname: 'news_aggregator_development')`. How is the pg gem supposed to know where your instance is, and how to authenticate to it?

Comment: specifying the information in the connect was the issue, thanks! If you post that as an answer I will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points:

1. Wrap your Sinatra helpers in a `helpers {}` block. This will allow you to use `settings.db_config` instead of `Sinatra::Application.db_config`:

   ```
   helpers do
     def db_connection
       connection = PG.connect(settings.db_config)
       yield connection
     ensure
       connection.close
     end
   end
   ```
2. In your `PG.connect` call, you should pass the host, user, password, and any other options necessary for the pg gem to find, connect, and authenticate to your instance. The `dbname` alone is not enough—at least not on Windows.

   ```
   configure :development do
     set :db_config, {
       host: "localhost",
       port: 5432, 
       user: "foo",
       password: "bar",
       dbname: "news_aggregator_development"
     }
   end
   ```

Good luck!